# Running Cumulative Interest calculation in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with structured data that looks like this:

| Person ID | Interest Model ID | Year | Interest Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | -0.05 |
| A | 1 | 2 | -0.05 |
| A | 1 | 3 | -0.05 |
| A | 2 | 1 | -0.1 |
| A | 2 | 2 | -0.1 |

I would like to add a column that is a running cumulative interest rate, so for instance, for the above data:

| Person ID | Interest Model ID | Year | Interest Rate | Cumulative Interest Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | -0.05 | 0.95 |
| A | 1 | 2 | -0.05 | 0.9 |
| A | 1 | 3 | -0.05 | 0.85 |
| A | 2 | 1 | -0.1 | 0.765 |
| A | 2 | 2 | -0.1 | 0.6885 |

Cumulative Interest for this purpose is a funny calculation, and is calculated in this way:

For every Interest Model ID, it can be calculated as

```
    (1 + (interest_rate * year) ) * base_interest_rate
```

With the year being the amount of years with the same interest rate.

The difficult part is that the base_interest_rate starts off as 1, but with every new interest rate, it will be the final cumulative interest rate of the previous rate.

For instance

| Year | Interest Rate | Cumulative Interest | Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.05 | 0.95 | `(1+(-0.05*1)) * 1` |
| 2 | -0.05 | 0.9 | `(1+(-0.05*2)) * 1` |
| 3 | -0.05 | 0.85 | `(1+(-0.05*3)) * 1` |
| 1 | -0.1 | 0.765 | `(1+(-0.1*1)) * 0.85` |
| 2 | -0.1 | 0.6885 | `(1+(-0.1*2)) * 0.85` |

Is there a way to make this work in pyspark? My initial attempts have been to try window functions but I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

Comment: why the first calculation is `(1+(-0.05*0)) * 1` (with year = 1) while the 4th calculation is `(1+(-0.1*1)) * 0.9` (also with year=1)?

Comment: @pltc it is because of the base interest rate: "The difficult part is that the base_interest_rate starts off as 1, but with every new interest rate, it will be the final cumulative interest rate of the previous rate."

Comment: No I'm asking about `* year` part, both of them has `year = 1` but 1st one is `*0` and 4th is `*1`

Comment: @pltc you're totally right, that's my mistake! I've corrected it in the question

Comment: hm, if that's the case, then `(1+(-0.1*1)) * 0.9` should be `(1+(-0.1*1)) * 0.85`?

Comment: @pltc definitely. Sorry about all the mistakes. All the calculations and formulae should be accurate now in all the tables.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried some different ways but I still cannot achieve your expected output. I'm putting here what I have so far, not a complete answer but hopefully, you can pick something up from it. The overall idea is to use 1 as the initial `base_rate` to calculate the accumulation rate, then update it later.

```py
step1 = (df
    .withColumn('base_rate', F.lit(1))
    .withColumn('cum_rate', (1 + (F.col('rate') * (F.col('year'))) ) * F.col('base_rate'))
)
step1.show()

# +---------+-----+----+-----+---------+--------+
# |person_id|im_id|year| rate|base_rate|cum_rate|
# +---------+-----+----+-----+---------+--------+
# |        A|    1|   1|-0.05|        1|    0.95|
# |        A|    1|   2|-0.05|        1|     0.9|
# |        A|    1|   3|-0.05|        1|    0.85|
# |        A|    2|   1| -0.1|        1|     0.9|
# |        A|    2|   2| -0.1|        1|     0.8|
# +---------+-----+----+-----+---------+--------+

step2 = (step1
    .groupBy('person_id', 'im_id')
    .agg(F.last('cum_rate').alias('last_cum_rate'))
)
step2.show()
# +---------+-----+-------------+
# |person_id|im_id|last_cum_rate|
# +---------+-----+-------------+
# |        A|    2|          0.8|
# |        A|    1|         0.85|
# +---------+-----+-------------+

(step1
    .join(step2, on=['person_id', 'im_id'])
    .orderBy('person_id', 'im_id')
    .withColumn('prev_rate', F.lag('rate', 1).over(W.partitionBy('person_id').orderBy('im_id', 'year')))
    .withColumn('rate_changed', F
        .when(F.col('prev_rate').isNull(), False)
        .otherwise(F.col('prev_rate') != F.col('rate'))
    )
    .show()
)
# +---------+-----+----+-----+---------+--------+-------------+---------+------------+
# |person_id|im_id|year| rate|base_rate|cum_rate|last_cum_rate|prev_rate|rate_changed|
# +---------+-----+----+-----+---------+--------+-------------+---------+------------+
# |        A|    1|   1|-0.05|        1|    0.95|         0.85|     null|       false|
# |        A|    1|   2|-0.05|        1|     0.9|         0.85|    -0.05|       false|
# |        A|    1|   3|-0.05|        1|    0.85|         0.85|    -0.05|       false|
# |        A|    2|   1| -0.1|        1|     0.9|          0.8|    -0.05|        true|
# |        A|    2|   2| -0.1|        1|     0.8|          0.8|     -0.1|       false|
# +---------+-----+----+-----+---------+--------+-------------+---------+------------+
```